# Could we have smallcaps formatting?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, markdown

[It's bad to use fake smallcaps](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6735/is-the-accusation-that-smallcaps-significantly-hurts-my-questions-software-comp/6736), and true smallcaps formatting would benefit a number of sites. [Role-playing Games](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/), for example, has a convention of formatting game terminology in the same manner as in its manuals.  [Polaris](http://www.tao-games.com/polaris/) (and a number of similar games from the same author) uses smallcaps to denote certain kinds of game terms.  Could we get smallcaps implemented [if a community decides they want it?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6766/can-we-have-smallcaps)

Comment: This should probably be on the per-site Meta.

Comment: I wanted to ask if an implementation would be a reasonable feature request.  Like, what are the technological/development hurdles? (If you still think that goes elsewhere I'll delete this, I just wanna check)

Comment: I don't think MarkDown supports small caps yet, but it would be nice

Comment: SE site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) has some posts that use a small caps constructed with subscript & superscript. See [1](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/).  This is difficult, and a smallcaps Markdown syntax might be helpful.   (My understanding is that official Markdown does not include this feature yet).   The [linked meta Q&A](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6735/is-the-accusation-that-smallcaps-significantly-hurts-my-questions-software-comp/6736) makes a very good case that "extended unicode" is not the right way to do Small caps.